# Find differences based on date

Tags: mysql

I have a table product table where zones can change regularly.I need to find a product only if the zone has changed.
My data looks like this

```
ProductID 123
zones west
Addate 08/12/2018
rate 5.00

ProductID 123
zones east
Addate 08/12/2018
rate 10.00

ProductID 123
Region west
Addate 08/13/2018
rate 10.00

ProductID 123
zones east
Addate 08/13/2018
rate 10.00
```

Tabular format:

```
ProductID | zones | Addate | rate
123 | west | 08/12/2018 | 5.00
123 | east | 08/12/2018 | 10.00
123 | west | 08/13/2018 | 10.00
123 | east | 08/13/2018 | 10.00
```

and my query below should not return any data since no zones have changed in the last two days but it brings back both records. Can you tell me how I can re write this.

```
Select A.zones as newArea,B.zones as oldArea ,A.Addate newdate,B.Addate as olddate
from Products A,Products B
where A.ProductId=B.ProductId
and A.Addate=CURDATE()
and B.Addate=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
and A.zones<>B.zones
```

Comment: It is hard to read/visualize your data as your have pasted it above.  Can you post it in a tabular format instead?

Comment: Actually, zones have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could write a query that return rows for today that don't have a matching row from yesterday.  We can use an *anti-join* pattern.

```
SELECT A.zones    AS newarea
     , A.addate   AS newdate
 FROM Products A
 LEFT 
 JOIN Products B
   ON B.productid = A.productid
  AND B.addate    = CURDATE() + INTERVAL -1 DAY
  AND B.zones     = A.zones
WHERE B.productid IS NULL 
  AND A.addate = CURDATE()
```

We could then also add an outer join to `Products` to find a row that matches except on zone...

```
SELECT A.zones    AS newarea
     , C.zones    AS oldarea
     , A.addate   AS newdate
 FROM Products A
 LEFT 
 JOIN Products B
   ON B.productid = A.productid
  AND B.addate    = CURDATE() + INTERVAL -1 DAY
  AND B.zones     = A.zones
 LEFT
 JOIN Products C
   ON C.productid = A.productid
  AND C.addate    = CURDATE() + INTERVAL -1 DAY
  AND C.zones    <> A.zones
WHERE B.productid IS NULL
  AND A.addate = CURDATE()
```

---

Recommendation: Ditch the old school comma syntax for the inner join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead.